# How to run Windows on MacBook after installing it using Boot Camp Assistant?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

The following things I've done so far:

- Download the ISO image of Windows from Microsoft.
- Using Boot Camp Assistant I successfully installed Windows 10 on my MacBook.
- Windows is running perfectly.
- While in Windows there is **Boot Camp Control Panel** to restart the MacBook using OS X.
- Now I am running OS X.

The question is:

**How can I restart the MacBook to run Windows from OS X?**

Answer (score 1):

Two ways...

1. If you want it to restart in Windows every time until told otherwise

   System Preferences > Startup Disk
   Click on the Windows boot partition & hit Restart...
2. If you want to choose just this time, then back to Mac next reboot

   At the boot chimes, hold the  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  key [ labelled  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  on some keyboards] until you see a choice of boot volumes appear on the screen.
   Click Windows & then the arrow under it.

Number 1. is the equivalent of the Windows Boot Camp control panel, which makes the change "until told otherwise"